# Eclipse PDE: Get full path of an external file open in Workbench

Tags: pde

I am writing an Eclipse Plugin which requires me to get full path of any kind of file open in the Workspace.

I am able to get full path of any file which is part of any Eclipse project. Code to get open/active editor file from workspace.

```
public static String getActiveFilename(IWorkbenchWindow window) {
        IWorkbenchPage activePage = window.getActivePage();
        IEditorInput input = activePage.getActiveEditor().getEditorInput();
        String name = activePage.getActiveEditor().getEditorInput().getName();
        PluginUtils.log(activePage.getActiveEditor().getClass() +" Editor.");
        IPath path = input instanceof FileEditorInput ? ((FileEditorInput) input).getPath() : null;
        if (path != null) {
            return path.toPortableString();
        }
        return name;
    }
```

However, if any file is `drag-dropped in Workspace` or opened using `File -> Open File`. For instance, I opened a file from /Users/mac/log.txt from File -> Open File. My plugin is not able to find location of this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple of days search, I found the answer by looking at the source code of Eclipse IDE.

In IDE.class, Eclipse tries to find a suitable editor input depending on the workspace file or an external file. Eclipse handles files in workspace using `FileEditorInput` and external files using `FileStoreEditorInput`. Code snippet below:

```
/**
     * Create the Editor Input appropriate for the given <code>IFileStore</code>.
     * The result is a normal file editor input if the file exists in the
     * workspace and, if not, we create a wrapper capable of managing an
     * 'external' file using its <code>IFileStore</code>.
     *
     * @param fileStore
     *            The file store to provide the editor input for
     * @return The editor input associated with the given file store
     * @since 3.3
     */
    private static IEditorInput getEditorInput(IFileStore fileStore) {
        IFile workspaceFile = getWorkspaceFile(fileStore);
        if (workspaceFile != null)
            return new FileEditorInput(workspaceFile);
        return new FileStoreEditorInput(fileStore);
    }
```

I have modified the code posted in the question to handle both files in Workspace and external file.

```
public static String getActiveEditorFilepath(IWorkbenchWindow window) {
        IWorkbenchPage activePage = window.getActivePage();
        IEditorInput input = activePage.getActiveEditor().getEditorInput();


        String name = activePage.getActiveEditor().getEditorInput().getName();
        //Path of files in the workspace.
        IPath path = input instanceof FileEditorInput ? ((FileEditorInput) input).getPath() : null;
        if (path != null) {
            return path.toPortableString();
        }

        //Path of the externally opened files in Editor context.
        try {
            URI urlPath = input instanceof FileStoreEditorInput ? ((FileStoreEditorInput) input).getURI() : null;
            if (urlPath != null) {
                return new File(urlPath.toURL().getPath()).getAbsolutePath();
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Fallback option to get at least name
        return name;
    }
```